# Equally expand size of 2 divs

Tags: html, css

I am making template for html raport. I have problem with sizing this `<div class="rule"></div>`. I have two divs of this kind. I want then to be equally size, displayed next to each other and 2 of this div should take all avialible space of `<div class="right_container"></div>`.
Final efect sholud be similar to this: [image]

I tried this but in smaller resolution screen second rule div goes to next line.

```
.rule{
  height:300px;
  width: 48%;
  background-color: rgb(55,55,55);
  border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Is there any CSS Properties that can achive this?

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.left_container {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.right_container {
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.right_container_plot {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.rule {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.label {
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
  font: 20pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left_container">
    <p class="label">Transactions</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right_container">
    <div class="rule">
      <p class="label">Buy rule</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rule">
      <p class="label">Sell rule</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right_container_plot">
    <p class="label">Plot</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `display: flex;` to `right_container` class.

A flex container expands items to fill available free space or shrinks them to prevent overflow.

See below link for more info about CSS display property:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: your answer resolver only half of my problems. Still 2 ```<div class="rule">``` aren't expanded equally to all avialible size of ```<div class="right_container">```. I want to achive effect similar to screen in question.

Comment: Add `width: 100%;` to your `rule` class. this property maximize width of each div to fill their parent div (with `right_container` class).